# printing a array values in ascending and descending order in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I wrote this below program to print the array by getting i/p from user but shows a compiling error.  And i want a program print those input in ascending and descending order.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[10] = {};  // ![enter image description here][1]
    for (int i = 0; a[i] <= 9; i++)
      {
        cout << "Enter the numbers:" << endl;
        cin >> a[i];
      }
    cout << a[i] << endl;
}
```

**error:**

```
![error by codeblocks][1]

||=== Build: Debug in example (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
H:\c++\example\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
H:\c++\example\main.cpp|12|error: name lookup of 'i' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]|
H:\c++\example\main.cpp|12|note: (if you use '-fpermissive' G++ will accept your code)|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Whats the error? And where is your sorting code?

Comment: You should put the text of the error here so we can see it.

Comment: You'll need a loop when printing them out, also.

Comment: i dont know how to get input properly and to sort the array elements..pls help

Comment: The key to successful programming is often to divide the problem: (1) make code to print a list, (2) make code to sort a list, (3) make code to read a list as user input, (4) combine your efforts.

Comment: The error is for using `i` after the `for` block. The way that you have defined the variables right now, `i` goes out of scope when the `for` block ends. if you want to print the array, use another `for` for printing. Also, I think your for should look like `for(int i=0;i<=9;...` and not `for(int i=0;a[i]<=9;...`.

Comment: main should return an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should print numbers in a loop, and also your loop condition seems wrong. this would work:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[10];
    int i;
    cout << "Enter the numbers:" << endl;

    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }

}
```

and if you want to show them sorted, you have to use sort() first.